# Bounds of periodic functions formed from infinite series of shifts

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, periodic-functions, almost-periodic-function

Recently, I have become quite obsessed with the follow series:

$$f(t,x)=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^m f(t+x m)$$

where $f$ is analytic. This series automatically produces a periodic function with period $2x$ (assuming it converges). Let use focus on four seemingly similar functions of the form $g(t)e^{-h(t)}$:

$$\begin{align}
f1(t)&=t e^{-t^2} \\
f2(t)&=\tanh(t) e^{-\cosh(t)} \\
f3(t)&=\tanh(t/2) e^{-\cosh(t)} \\
f4(t)&=t e^{-\cosh(t)} 
\end{align}$$

There is an interplay between the increasing behavior of $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ that I don't understand. In particular, I would like to know when $f(t,x)$ is positive on the first quarter of it's periodicity, that is when $t\in (0,x/2)$.

Using mathematica, it appears that $f1$ and $f2$ are never negative. In fact, it appears:

$$f(t,x)>(f(x/2,x)/(x/2)) * t$$

for all $t\in(0,x/2)$. However, $f3$ and $f4$ appear to fail being positive. Indeed, focusing on $f4$ and choosing $x\approx 0.82$, it appears that $f(t,x)<0$ for all $t\in(0,x/2)$. The split appears to be at $c\approx 0.919583$. Zooming in very very close to zero, it does appear that at $c$, $f4$ has multiple simple zeros being both positive and negative. However, to the right and left of this value $f4$ appears to be either all positive or all negative.

Likewise, for $c\approx 0.61093879$ and function $f3$, it appears that $f(t,x)$ is positive for $x>c$ and negative for $x<c$, again for $t\in(0,x/2)$. This is very surprising considering the extreme similarity of $f2$ and $f3$. Also, zooming in very very close to zero at $x\approx 0.61093879$ it does not appear that $f3$ has any simple zeros, meaning that is appears there exists some constant $c\approx 0.61093879 $, such that

$$\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^m \tanh((t+cm)/2)e^{-\cosh(t+cm)}=0$$

for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. That seems very interesting.

Question: Is it indeed the case for $f2$, that $f(t,x)>0$ for all $t\in(0,x/2)$? Moreover is $f(t,x)>(f(x/2,x)/(x/2)) * t$?

Comment: There should be only one question in one post. You seems to have four questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little too long for a comment, but I hope it might help.

---

Note that the function $$f_a(t,x) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^m k_a(t+mx)$$ $$k_a(t) = (t+a t^3) e^{-t^2} $$ for $a \geq 0$ should satisfy all the requirements you ask - $k_a(t)$ can be written as $h(t)e^{-g(t)}$ where $h(t)$ is odd, has a simple zero at $t=0$, and is positive on the positive real line, and $g(t)$ is even.

In the following, limit oneself to the case of $x=1$.

Notice that
$$l_1(t) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^m (t+m) e^{-(t+m)^2}$$ is positive on the interval $t \in (0,1)$ by inspection in Mathematica.

Notice also that $$l_3(t) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^m (t+m)^3 e^{-(t+m)^2}$$ is negative on the same interval by inspection in Mathematica.

Note that $f_a(t,1) = l_1(t)+a l_3(t)$. Let $a^*$ be the value of $a$ for which $a<a^*$ has $f_a(t,1)$ being positive everywhere on the interval $t \in (0,1)$ and for which $a>a^*$ has $f_a(t,1)$ negative on at least part of this interval.

It's tempting to me that there's some small epsilon for which $f_{a^*+\epsilon}(t,1)$ has at least one simple zero on the interval $t\in(0,1)$ - I think the only way to avoid this is if $f_3(t) = -\frac{1}{a^*}f_1(t)$ (so that one goes abruptly from being positive on the interval $t \in (0,1)$ to negative on the interval), which would be very surprising to me.

---

Edit: Curiously, $\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^m (t+m) e^{-(t+m)^2}$ and $\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^m (t+m)^3 e^{-(t+m)^2}$ are very nearly (numerically) proportional for $t \in (0,1)$, with a proportionality constant of $\approx -1.0337$. Perhaps this points to the origin of the difficulty in seeing a simple zero.

This (approximate?) proportionality weakens as the argument in the exponential grows, and I think I've found my desired counterexample:

$$f(t,x) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^m k(t+mx)$$
$$k(t) = (t+38 t^3) e^{-1.6 t^2}$$

[image: Plot showing a couple simple zeros]

However, this is merely numerical and perhaps not entirely convincing - I'd welcome others to probe this function, especially given that it appears quite close to zero everywhere on the interval.

---

Edit 2:
We can reach a strong understanding of the behavior of these series by noting the following:

For $$f(t,x) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^m k(t+mx),$$ if one Fourier expands $$f(t,x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n(x) e^{2 n \pi i \frac{t}{2x}},$$ one finds that the Fourier coefficient $a_n(x)$ is directly related to the Fourier transform of $k$: $$a_{2n}(x)=0, \,\,\,\, a_{2n+1}(x) = \frac{1}{x}\hat{k}\left(\frac{2n+1}{2x}\right)$$ where $$\hat{k}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2\pi i \omega t} k(t) dt$$

This links the properties of the $f(t,x)$ series to the Fourier transformation of $k(t)$. I think there is a wealth of information to be gleaned from this. In the following, I'll largely consider the regime of small $x$.

The functions considered in the question and answer are smooth, so their Fourier coefficients decay very rapidly. For small $x$, this means that the dominant contributions to the Fourier series for $f(x,t)$ comes from $a_1(x)$ and $a_{-1}(x)$, with subleading contributions from $a_3(x)$ and $a_{-3}(x)$. Since $k(t)$ is taken to be odd for this question, this gives a Fourier sine series that is dominated by $\sin(2 \pi \frac{t}{2x})$ with a subleading $\sin(2 \pi \frac{3 t}{2x})$ for small $x$.

This explains some of the curious features of my example with $k(t) =(t+38 t^3) e^{-1.6 t^2}$ - the numbers of $38$ and $1.6$ here incidentally work out to nearly cancel the $\sin(2 \pi \frac{t}{2x}) = \sin(\pi t)$ contribution for $x=1$, leaving the subleading small $\sin(2 \pi \frac{3t}{2x}) = \sin(3 \pi t)$ contribution. This behavior is indeed confirmed in the plot above. I had found the numbers $38$ and $1.6$ by hand in Mathematica, but using the Fourier transforms of $t e^{-t^2}$ and $t^3 e^{-t^2}$ should allow one to get a nice analytic handle on choices of coefficients to cancel out the leading behavior of $\sin(2 \pi \frac{t}{2x})$ at small $x$, and to similarly estimate the relative size of the subleading $\sin(2 \pi \frac{3t}{2x})$ contribution.

Comment: Ah yes, this is an interesting point. I was avoiding non-simple zeros on purpose, mostly as an effort to keep things simplistic. While technically your example does have simple zeros, in the limit you are essentially creating very tiny perturbations of a function with a non-simple zero. Will have to do some investigation of this. It would be interesting if the distance to the imaginary roots plays a role in the observations.

Comment: @BobbyOcean Fingers crossed, a small modification of my original proposed function indeed gets a couple simple zeros, see my edit above. However, there's a mystery remaining of why $\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^m (t+m) e^{-(t+m)^2}$ and $\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^m (t+m)^3 e^{-(t+m)^2}$ appear to be very close to proportional on the interval of $t \in (0,1)$.

Comment: @BobbyOcean I think I understand why $\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^m (t+m) e^{-(t+m)^2}$ and $\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^m (t+m)^3 e^{-(t+m)^2}$ look nearly proportional - it's because both are nearly proportional to $\sin(\pi t)$! That is, the Fourier series for both of these functions has coefficients that are rapidly decaying, leaving mostly just $\sin(\pi t)$. I think the rapid decay of the Fourier coefficients might be a key clue.

Comment: It does appear to be the case that $f$ has simple roots for $x=1$. However, this does appear to be very very brief and does not appear to be true for $x$ outside of $[.9999,1.001]$. Likewise, at $x=1.01$, $f$ appears to have a maximum value of $\approx 0.45$ which is several hundred times larger than the function at $x=1$.  There is some property here like "if $f$ has a simple zero, then $f$ is uniformly very close to zero".

Comment: I have modified the question to make it more accurate and straight to the question. Moreover, it appears your observation is non-trivial. Indeed, the $f4$ function also appears to have the property you found.

Comment: @BobbyOcean Would you consider maybe changing the question to be your original question 1 of whether one can have simple zeroes within the interval $t \in (0,x)$ (and potentially accepting this answer :) ), and then asking your edited question as a separate question?

Comment: @BobbyOcean Whatever you decide re: the question, please check out my most recent edit - there's a nice formula for the Fourier series for $f(t,x)$ in terms of the Fourier transform of $k(t)$ in my notation (in your notation, you use $f(t)$ for what I call $k(t)$, which I feel overloads $f$ a little too much for my tastes). This explains the small $x$ behavior of $f(x,t)$.

Comment: Sure, I went ahead and split off the second part for you. We should note that rewriting the periodic infinite sum back as a fourier transform appears to only be useful when we actually know what the fourier transform is. In the case of $f(t)=t*\exp(-t^2)$ this is obvious, but in the case of $f(t)=\tanh(t)\exp(-\cosh(t))$ this is not obvious at all. The explicit relationship is $$\int_0^\infty f(t) \sin(x t) dt= \int_0^{\pi/x} f(t,\pi/x) \sin(x t) dt$$ In other words any fourier transform can be written as the finite fouier transform of a periodic function.

Comment: The point here is that I successfully eliminate the $\sin(xt)$ and integral. The only question is now if the periodic function is positive on the first half of it's period.